# Input several images in tensorflow session.run()

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a code that uses tensorflow to analyse some images with a GPU, I use the tf.session and introduce the frames in the session.run for the model as

```py
with tf.Session() as sess:
    res, img = cap.read()
    heatmaps_result, offsets_result, displacement_fwd_result, displacement_bwd_result = sess.run(model_outputs,feed_dict={'image:0': my_batch[0]})
```

As I am running this on a GPU it has spare space so I would want to introduce several images. I have tried what was said in [Bach several images in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48110514/how-to-batch-multiple-videoframes-before-run-tensorflow-inference-session), but I obtain the error:

"The name 'image_tensor:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'image_tensor', does not exist in the graph."

I have introduce the images in a bach as:

```py
cnt = 0
my_batch = list()
while (cnt < 5):
    cnt = cnt + 1
    res, img = cap.read()
    if not res:
        break
    my_batch.append(img)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a placeholder with the name 'image:0' as when using feed_dict you need to give the name corresponding the input placeholder.